# Excel - selecting range on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010, trying to build collection from range and then copy it into another worksheet using this code:

```
Set g_colTGDNames = New Collection

Worksheets("CONF").Activate
Range("TGDNames").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    g_colTGDNames.Add ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Worksheets("TGDOut").Activate
Range("SymbolsOUT").Select
For Each obj In g_colTGDNames
    ActiveCell.Value = CStr(obj)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
```

Collection builds successfuly, but after I switch worksheets I got 
[error 1004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73DCp.png) on line

```
Range("SymbolsOUT").Select
```

I have no idea why, it works when i'm building collection. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to select ranges first to build a collection. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194). That being said. Do you actually have a named range called "SymbolsOUT" on that specific worksheet?

Comment: Yes, I do. I've tried to just copy those to ranges with Set rngIN = Range("TGDNames") and Set rngOUT = Range("SymbolsOUT") and one on 1st worksheet works fine while second one returns same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you get an error because you try to select a range that does not exist. Why ?

```vb
Range("SymbolsOUT").Select
```

means actually

```vb
'Select the range "SymbolsOUT" from the worksheet where your function is written
Me.Range("SymbolsOUT").Select
```

What you really want is

```vb
ActiveSheet.Range("SymbolsOUT").Select
```

Now, the @JvdV comment is totally right : you don't need to use `Select` and `Activate` to achieve what you are doing. It makes the code messy and furthermore it is really a pain for performances :

```vb
Dim mycell as Range
Set mycell = Worksheets("TGDOut").Range("SymbolsOUT")
Do Until mycell.Value = ""
    g_colTGDNames.Add mycell.Value
    Set myCell = myCell.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Okey now i understand, thanks for tips and code sample.

Comment: And to add more speed, loopt through an array instead of a range =), + for the clear answer.